Very disturbing foreign movie about twin brothers and their mother
Details I remember:

No father
Very isolated house
All family members have blond hair and very palid skin
Constant torture scenes and painful moments
Mother is totally insane
North-european language, as far as I remember 
Movie released around 2015 (not sure about that)


Welcome to Movies.SE! We have a minimum requirement for ID questions on this site. Do you remember when/where/how you watched this movie? What language was it in? Was it an American production, or from a different country? Was it real life or animated? Was it in color? We'll need answers to these questions to help us track down an answer to this question.  If you have this information, please edit it into your question.

It sounds like the austrian film Ich seh ich seh (translated as "Goodnight mommy").
From 2014, and it has all the elements you mention. Here is the Trailer:




An amazing movie, I might add

Absolutely, forgot the title because of another movie: "The eyes of my mother"

I'll have to check that one out!
